# Get some contact info data from phone

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I need to get list of *id*, *first name*, *last name*, *number(or numbers)*, *email*, *website* of an android device contacts. I know by getting id I can query about phone numbers this is not a big deal. But I don't know how I should make query to get all these columns correctly.

I supposed for names I need **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName** for email I need **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS** ,for id **Contacts** and for website **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL**.

My code returns strange values like a single digit number for GIVEN_NAME, null for FAMILY_NAME, one of contact numbers for Email.ADDRESS.

However I think the problem is query URI, which one should I use?

```
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

String[] projection = new String[] {
                    Contacts._ID,
                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};

Cursor nameCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
   String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
   String family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
   String email = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
   Integer id= nameCur.getInt(nameCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
   String website = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL));
//do some work with strings...                
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:
first we need a query for getting all contact id in the table of "raw_contacts"

```
List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
// Row contacts content uri( access raw_contacts table. ).
Uri rawContactUri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
// Return _id column in contacts raw_contacts table.
String queryColumnArr[] = {ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID};
// Query raw_contacts table and return raw_contacts table _id.
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(rawContactUri, queryColumnArr, null, null, null);
```

then we query table "data" for extra information for each contact id:

```
// Data content uri (access data table. )
Uri dataContentUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
// Build query columns name array.
List<String> queryColumnList = new ArrayList<String>();
// ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID = "contact_id";
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
// ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = "mimetype";
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA4);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA5);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA6);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA7);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA8);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA9);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA10);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA11);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA12);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA13);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA14);
queryColumnList.add(ContactsContract.Data.DATA15);
// Translate column name list to array.
String queryColumnArr[] = queryColumnList.toArray(new String[queryColumnList.size()]);
// Build query condition string. Query rows by contact id.
StringBuffer whereClauseBuf = new StringBuffer();
whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
whereClauseBuf.append("=");
whereClauseBuf.append(rawContactId);
// Query data table and return related contact data.
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(dataContentUri, queryColumnArr, whereClauseBuf.toString(), null, null);
```

last cursor contains all the data of any contact and for get that data we need switch case:

```
String mimeType =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
switch (mimeType) {
            // Get email data.
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:
                // Email.ADDRESS == data1
                String emailAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
                int emailType = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                data.setDataType(emailType);
                data.setDataValue(emailAddress);
                ret1.add(data);
                con.setEmailList(ret1);
                break;
            // Get organization data.
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:
                // Organization.COMPANY == data1
                String company = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY));
             con.setCompany(company);
                break;
            // Get phone number.
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:
                // Phone.NUMBER == data1
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                // Phone.TYPE == data2
                int phoneTypeInt = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                data.setDataType(phoneTypeInt);
                data.setDataValue(phoneNumber);
                ret1.add(data);
                con.addPhoneList(ret1);
                break;
            // Get display name.
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:
                // StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME == data1
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME == data2
                String givenName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                // StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME == data3
                String familyName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                ret.add("Display Name : " + displayName);
                ret.add("Given Name : " + givenName);
                ret.add("Family Name : " + familyName);           
                break;
            // Get website.
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:
                // Website.URL == data1
                String websiteUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL));
                // Website.TYPE == data2
                int websiteTypeInt = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE));
                String websiteTypeStr = getEmailTypeString(websiteTypeInt);
                ret.add("Website Url : " + websiteUrl);
                ret.add("Website Type Integer : " + websiteTypeInt);
                ret.add("Website Type String : " + websiteTypeStr);
                break;
        }
```

this is not my compelete code just for getting idea. hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the sub-tables you're trying to access (`Email`, `Phone`, `Website`, etc.) are actually all stored in a single big table called `Data`.
All those sub-tables share the same fields Data1-Data15, so by querying on the `Phone.CONTENT_URI` table, you're only getting `Phone` info, that's why trying to access `StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME` on the result is wrong.

Instead you query over the `Data.CONTENT_URI` table that contains all info, and you differentiate between rows of different data type via the value at `Data.MIMETYPE`.

See docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data

I'm not sure if you needed the contact's info for all contacts on the device, or for a specific one.

Here's the code to get info of a single contact (you need to assign value to the `contactId` variable there)

```
String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3};

// query only emails/phones/events
String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId + " AND " + 
                   Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE"', '" + Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1); // full name
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of data (phone / birthday / email)
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    String kind = "unknown";

    switch (mime) {
        case StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            String firstName = cur.getString(4);
            String lastName = cur.getString(5);
            Log.d(TAG, "got name: " + data + " - " + firstName + " " + lastName);
            break;
        case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            Log.d(TAG, "got phone: " + data);
            break;
        case Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            Log.d(TAG, "got email: " + data);
            break;
        case Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            Log.d(TAG, "got website: " + data);
            break;
    }
}
cur.close();
```

To convert it to run over ALL contacts, simply remove the `Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId` part from the `selection`, and then you'll need to create some HashMap from contactId to an object containing the info about that contact (use the `id` variable for the key)

Comment: thank you for your code and answer, it was so helpful. by the way, I guess I must go deeper in android contact database. I found this link very informative https://www.dev2qa.com/android-contacts-fields-data-table-columns-and-data-mimetype-explain/ for others who want to learn. I will post the result soon.